# how to add Highway Wrapper to multilayered bidirectional lstm in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, bidirectional

I'm trying to add Highway Wrapper or Residual Wrapper to a bidirectional LSTM in tensorflow. The code is as below:

```
def lstm_cell(self):
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=self.num_units, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True, initializer=orthogonal_initializer())
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.HighwayWrapper(cell)

cells_fw = [self.lstm_cell() for _ in range(self.layer_num)]                                                                                                                                   
cells_bw = [self.lstm_cell() for _ in range(self.layer_num)]                                                                                                                                   
outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cells_fw=cells_fw, cells_bw=cells_bw, inputs=self.features, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Each layer of tf.contrib.rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn will output a tensor whose depth is num_units * 2(concatenated by forward and backward output). So the depth of output is num_units * 2. But the depth of input is num_units, which is not equal to output. When using Highway Wrapper, the dimension of input and output must be same. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to implement the rnn_fw and rnn_bw yourself, and add the residual connections to them separately. Then you can concatenate their outputs, and use the concatenated vector as the input to the higher level bi-rnn.